# how to get the last element index after using list.append() in python

Tags: python, list

Why the idx = None?

```
myList = []
idx = myList.append("abc")
print myList
print idx
print myList[0]
```

print result is:

```
['abc']
None
abc
```

Comment: MyList.append() doesn't give you anything. append() method simply appends i.e. its a void. You are thinking of it as a database insert command which should return the index at which it was inserted.

Comment: `append` doesn't return any value. You have to do `myList.index("abc")`

Comment: @Figo What's your actual question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

"*You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default None. [1](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.*"

Answer (score 3):

You can get last element using `list[-1]` which is cool. Python is cool.

And if you really want `list.append()` to return you a value you should create your own class inherited from `list` and redefine `append()` function

Comment: i think this is not he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Because append method doesn't return any value. It will just append the element to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The last element's index is `len(myList)-1`.

func append return nothing.

Comment: much better to use mylist[-1]

Comment: wait,he want the index of last element!

Answer (score 0):

See the doc below in my PyCharm

```
class list(object)  
    def append(self, x) 
Inferred type: (self: list[T], x: T) -> None
```

so `idx = myList.append("abc")` will let idx be None because append method just return it.

Answer (score 0):

The `.append` function doesn't return the index of the new element (in fact, it returns nothing), so index is assigned to "None".

If you want the index of the last element, it's one less than the length of the list, `len(myList) -1`.